# How I can generate Faraday Timeout Error Manually in Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby, timeout, faraday

I have a ruby on rails application which hit salesforce api and log the error. There are some scenarios where system is generate ReadNet Timeout error. I just wanted to generate the error manually so I can handle different logics in my code

Answer (score 2):

From the [Ref](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/issues/812#issuecomment-414258614) I have found the solution that was exact thing I was looking for.

```
begin
  conn = Faraday::Connection.new('https://httpstat.us')
  conn.options.timeout = 1
  conn.options.open_timeout = 1
  conn.options
  # => #<Faraday::RequestOptions timeout=1, open_timeout=1>
  conn.get('/200?sleep=2000')
  # => Faraday::TimeoutError (Net::ReadTimeout)

rescue Exception => e
  #you can catch exception here
  debugger
end
```

Comment: It's allso possible to set timeout through initialize options: `Faraday::Connection.new('https://httpstat.us', request: { timeout: 1.second }).get('/200?sleep=2000')`